# Why This Error Can not find {http://www.alfresco.org/model/system/1.0}base.Read & What's mean

Tags: alfresco

I need to create a new class to use it as bootstrap to create folders and nodes

```
<bean id="com.ds.module.extensions.Core.securityRequirementBootstrap" class="com.ds.ui.bean.dialog.module.SecurityRequirementBootstrap" init-method="init">
  <property name="searchService">
     <ref bean="SearchService"/>
  </property>
  <property name="nodeService">
     <ref bean="NodeService"/>
  </property>      
    <property name="transactionService">
        <ref bean="transactionService" />
    </property>
</bean> 

public class SecurityRequirementBootstrap {
public void init() throws Exception{
    AuthenticationUtil.runAs(new RunAsWork<String>() {
        public String doWork() throws Exception {
            transaction = transactionService.getUserTransaction();
            transaction.begin();
            NodeUtil.checkSecurityPreRequesite(searchService,nodeService);
            transaction.commit();
            return "";
        }
    }, "admin");
}

public synchronized static final Node acquireSequencesFolder(SearchService searchService){
    NodeRef nodeRef = searchService.query(StoreRef.STORE_REF_WORKSPACE_SPACESSTORE,
            SearchService.LANGUAGE_LUCENE,"@"+NamespaceService.CONTENT_MODEL_PREFIX+"\\:"+ContentModel.PROP_NAME.getLocalName()+":\""+Constants.SEQUENCES_FOLDER_NODE_NAME_STRING+"\"").getNodeRef(0);
    if(nodeRef != null)
        return new Node(nodeRef);
    return null;
}
```

but this code will throws an exception

```
aused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can not find {http://www.alfresco.org/model/system/1.0}base.Read
at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.model.PermissionModel.getPermissionReference(PermissionModel.java:1321)
at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.PermissionServiceImpl.getPermissionReference(PermissionServiceImpl.java:956)
at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.PermissionServiceImpl.hasPermission(PermissionServiceImpl.java:976)
at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.acegi.ACLEntryAfterInvocationProvider.decideOld(ACLEntryAfterInvocationProvider.java:756)
at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.acegi.ACLEntryAfterInvocationProvider.decide(ACLEntryAfterInvocationProvider.java:528)
at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.acegi.ACLEntryAfterInvocationProvider.decide(ACLEntryAfterInvocationProvider.java:511)
at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.acegi.ACLEntryAfterInvocationProvider.decide(ACLEntryAfterInvocationProvider.java:298)
at net.sf.acegisecurity.afterinvocation.AfterInvocationProviderManager.decide(AfterInvocationProviderManager.java:107)
at net.sf.acegisecurity.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.afterInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:329)
at net.sf.acegisecurity.intercept.method.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:82)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.java:44)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.proceedWithAudit(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:217)
at org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.proceed(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:184)
at org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:137)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:107)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy36.query(Unknown Source)
at com.ds.ui.bean.dialog.util.NodeUtil.acquireSequencesFolder(NodeUtil.java:68)
at com.ds.ui.bean.dialog.util.NodeUtil.checkSequencesExistance(NodeUtil.java:327)
at com.ds.ui.bean.dialog.util.NodeUtil.checkSecurityPreRequesite(NodeUtil.java:455)
at com.ds.ui.bean.dialog.module.SecurityRequirementBootstrap$1.doWork(SecurityRequirementBootstrap.java:21)
at com.ds.ui.bean.dialog.module.SecurityRequirementBootstrap$1.doWork(SecurityRequirementBootstrap.java:1)
at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:508)
at com.ds.ui.bean.dialog.module.SecurityRequirementBootstrap.init(SecurityRequirementBootstrap.java:17)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

Comment: Could you please post also the code for `NodeUtil.acquireSequencesFolder`?

Comment: method added in the original post

Comment: Skuro, listen i'm calling this code in a bootstrap phase

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using an ACP to bootstap in your folders? That's how new folders and files are normally added in in Alfresco, see the core bootstrap file for examples of adding new folders

Comment: With bootstrap phase, do you mean you put that `bean` in `bootstrap-context.xml`?

Comment: Exactly, that is what i want to prepare folders and nodes once time while the alfresco start up

Comment: Yes, i set the bean in a bootstrap-context.xml

Answer (score 1):

The exception says that the repository can not find the Read permission for the sys:base type.

- Have you changed or overwritten the
  alfresco/model/permissionDefinitions.xml? If yes, you most likely have an error there.
- Another thing I noticed is, that you should always close your lucene resultsets using a [try finally pattern](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Search#try...finally_pattern).